# How to assign a Launch pad to a specific key in Cubase

Tags: midi, midi-controller-keyboard, ableton-live, cubase

I have just bought a Novation Launch key mini with East West Gold orchestra and I was wondering if there is a way to set the launch pads to a specific pitch. This is so I can have the key switches of the VST instrument changed.